# How to use Python and BeautifulSoup to parse text but include newlines

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

so the HTML code that I want to parse is like this

```
<a>Hello
<br/>
<br/>
World<br/>
```

I can get it to become

```
Hello


World
```

but I want it to be

```
Hello\n\nWorld
```

Can anyone give me any hints or tips on what I can do to show where the newlines are?

Comment: Improving your question would be great, so that everyone can reproduce your issue easily (html looks a bit strange). Take a minute to read - How to create [mcve] to show up what you already have done, produces the provided output and you exactly get stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would assume there are already newline characters in your result, but while printing your string, python automatically interprets these characters.

To avoid this behavior you can print your string as representation - [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
print(repr(soup.get_text()))
```

so you will get:

```
Hello\n\n\nWorld\n
```

#### Example

```
html = '''
<a>Hello
<br/>
<br/>
World<br/>
'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(repr(soup.get_text()))
```

#### Output

```
Hello\n\n\nWorld\n
```